Excel Parent-Child Array to identify and move children not working?
I use Excel 2019 on Windows.
I am trying to create a parent-child array that iterates through each row in the worksheet "Data".
The parent rows are identified where the value in column B starts with "xDay_".
The children are in Columns C to G starting with the same row as the parent down to, and including, the row above the next parent.
In each column for the children there is only one value except in Column C where the same value is on two different rows.
For each parent row found, it should set the parent cell and the range of children cells in columns C to G.
It then select the children cells and moves or pastes them in the row next to their parent cell so that all values are on the same row which would leave a number of blank rows in between each parent.
The plan is once the array is working correctly I will add in some VBA to remove all of the blank rows.
The borders in this image re just to show how the parent relates to the children.

Arrays are not something that I am good with so I am failing but below is my code so far.
It does not produce any errors but it also does nothing, literally.
Sub ArrangeParentChildArray()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim parentCell As Range
    Dim childRange As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    
    ' Find the last row with data in column B
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each parent row
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        ' Check if the cell value starts with "\00"
        If Left(ws.Cells(i, 2).Value, 3) = "\00" Then
            ' Set the parent cell
            Set parentCell = ws.Cells(i, 2)
            ' Set the range of children
            Set childRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 3), ws.Cells(i, 7)) ' Specify the worksheet for Cells
            ' Move the children to the row of their parent
            childRange.Cut Destination:=parentCell.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub


First off, there are some discrepancies between your description and the code used. You said parent rows are identified where the value in column B starts with "xDay_", but the code seems to be identifying parent rows where the value in column B starts with "\00". Based on your screenshot, however, it seems like the parent rows could simply be identified where the value in column B is not blank.
Also, the code is attempting to locate the last row with data by looking in column B. Based on your screenshot, this would NOT locate the last row, because the last row containing child records is in column F (Child 4). You'd be better off locating the last row with data by looking in column A, assuming the Index numbers are always present for each record.
Based on these assumptions, you could try the following code:
Option Explicit

Sub ArrangeParentChildArray()

' Set the worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

' Find the last row with data in column A
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Set the data range
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Range("B2:G" & lastRow)

' Load the data range into an array
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = rg.Value

' Loop thru the array, moving child records to their parent rows
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    ' Set the parent row, if a new parent exists
        If arr(i, 1) <> "" Then
            k = i
        ElseIf k > 0 Then
        ' Move any child records to their parent row
            For j = 2 To UBound(arr, 2)
                If arr(i, j) <> "" Then
                    arr(k, j) = arr(i, j)
                    arr(i, j) = Null
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i

' Write the modified array back to the worksheet
    rg.Value = arr

End Sub

